# how to include template with angularjs in a page without refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to inserting a html template into html `div` under my static menu
I tried to put it with controller and ng-include 
in this way that i set the url of template in controller and then call the url variable in 
ng-include but it does not work.
i want the menu be static and the templates under menu dynamically change.
in index file

```
<div><div ng-include src="{{url}}"></div></div>
```

in app.js file

```
$scope.url="'html/login.html'";
```

regards.

Comment: show the code that didn't work

Comment: use directive. In template write your html and append it on your dom.

Comment: not enough information

Comment: <div ng-controller="set">
  <button ng-click="setUrl()">set</button>
  <div ng-include src="{{url}}"></div>
 </div>

Comment: timeApp.controller('set',function($scope){
 $scope.call=function(){
  
  $scope.url="/html/login.html";
 };
});

Comment: it is better to ask that can i set value for ng-include in a controller?

Answer (score 0):

The way you assign the url is a bit weird (it may work in some way, but I can't validate right now).

Typically, this is how it should be done:

```
<div ng-include="url"></div>

$scope.url = "html/login.html";
```